# How to get output signal from TLC2652ACP

Tags: operational-amplifier

I need to use a TLC2652ACP for signal amplification. When I go through the datasheet, the pin diagram shows only one pin for output.

My questions are:

1. Which pins to use to get output?
2. How to determine capacitance values for CXA and CXB?

[image: Pin diagram]

[image: Functional diagram]

Answer (score 1):

Output signal as usual will be between "OUT" and GND. You will need at least a couple resistors to set the gain and something like a +/-5V supply with a ground between the two supplies. And bypass the power supplies with ceramic capacitors close to the chip. Something in the 0.1 to 1uF X7R type will work nicely.

The external Cxa/Cxb capacitors should be low dielectric absorption film capacitors in the 100nF to 1uF range according to the datasheet. I would pick something like 220nF polypropylene for the best performance. Parts like mylar film (0.5% DA) or **C0G** ceramic (0.6% DA) will work too, but they won't be ideal. C0G capacitors were not available in anything like 100nF 35 years ago when the datasheet was written, hence their disparaging reference. They're not terrible compared to polyester/mylar film, just slightly worse.

Comment: Thank you, @Spehre, for your suggestions. Can you please clarify how to use GND. My power supply does not have GND. Shall I use "OUT" and "VDD-" instead?

Comment: The chip can be used with a single supply since the input range includes the negative rail, however the output will not be able to swing all the way to the negative rail (also GND with a single supply) especially when sinking current. Both inputs need to be in the range 0~3.1V with a single 5V supply. The chip is specified with +/-5V. If you want to create a -5V supply capable of some mA output from a 5V rail you can do so with an inexpensive ICL7660 and a few small capacitors.

Answer (score 0):

The TLC2652 is an older chopper amplifier. Output is connected between pin no 6 and GND.The datasheet in the Theory of Operation section describes the function of CXA and CXB and indeed shows the lower side of the two capacitors being connected to VDD-

There may be some performance benefit if the two capacitors are high quality, balanced devices. An X2Y capacitor provides inherently close matching between the two capacitors contained within the structure. A NPO dielectric provides low leakage and good thermal-related capacitance stability. They are available from Johnson Dielectrics and others.

[image]